# Postgres - is there a better way to prevent having to extract the interval in this case when function twice?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, postgres-9.6

I have the following functions in postgres which simply accepts a timestampz and returns the age of a record as a string similar to Reddit:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ageFromTimestamp (t timestamp WITH TIME ZONE) 
RETURNS text as $$
DECLARE interval text;
BEGIN
    case 
    when extract(years from age(now(), t)) > 0 then interval = extract(years from age(now(), t)) || 'y';
    when extract(months from age(now(), t)) > 0 then interval = extract(months from age(now(), t)) || 'mo';
    when extract(days from age(now(), t)) > 0 then interval = extract(days from age(now(), t)) || 'd';
    when extract(hours from age(now(), t)) > 0 then interval = extract(hours from age(now(), t)) || 'h';
    when extract(minutes from age(now(), t)) > 0 then interval = extract(minutes from age(now(), t)) || 'm';
    when extract(seconds from age(now(), t)) > 0 then interval = ceil(extract(seconds from age(now(), t))) || 's';
    else interval = 'now';
    end case;
    return interval;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

This works perfectly fine. I am just curious if there is a better way  to prevent calculation of the `extract(years from age(now(), t))` twice?

I am new to postgres and sql so learning new things.

Comment: Sub-query that extracted all the individual pieces into individual fields?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a query?

```
select (case when a.y > 0 then a.y || 'y'
             when a.m > 0 then a.m || 'mo'
             . . . 
        end)
from (values (age(now()) as v(a) cross apply
     (values ( extract(year from v.a),
               extract(month from v.a),
               . . .
             )
     ) a(y, mo, . . .)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this extract everything though? In my example code, it jumps out of the `case when` as soon as it finds a true condition. In yours, won't it calculate all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Technically it should be possible if you change your `CASE` into nested `IF`'s and add a temporary variable, something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ageFromTimestamp (t timestamp WITH TIME ZONE) 
RETURNS text as $$
DECLARE 
    interval text;
    temp double precision;
BEGIN
    temp = extract(years from age(now(), t));
    IF temp > 0 THEN
        interval = extract(years from age(now(), t)) || 'y';
    ELSE
        temp = extract(months from age(now(), t));
        IF temp > 0 THEN
            interval = extract(months from age(now(), t)) || 'mo';
        ELSE
            ...
        END IF;
    END IF;
    return interval;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

This approach has a disadvantage, however: with your requirements it means 7 nested `IF`'s, which makes the function quite hard to read and maintain. TBH, I would just leave it as it is, unless you experience severe performance lags in its usage.